# Native IONIC Geolocation not working on Android devices.

Tags: android, ionic-framework, geolocation, geocoding, ionic-native

I am using Ionic together with the native *Geolocation* plugin to retrieve user position and sort a list of position by closest to the user. 
The Geolocation plugin works perfectly using `ionic serve` or `ionic lab` as well as iOS devices but it does not work on Android devices (nor simulator).

What other solution can I use to retrieve longitude and latitude of the user?

I'll attach the class where I use the Geolocation plugin here.

The **Location class** I access has a public static variable where I store the userLocation since will be modified in more classes.

`this.Location.load` just uses the user position to call a method in `Location` class to sort the list of places.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { ModalController, NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';
import { SharePopup } from '../share-popup/share-popup';
import { InAppBrowser } from 'ionic-native';
import { CamhsPage } from '../camhs-page/camhs-page';

import { Locations } from '../../providers/locations';
import { Platform } from 'ionic-angular';
import { Geolocation } from 'ionic-native';

@Component({
  selector: 'contact',
  templateUrl: 'contact.html'
})
export class Contact {
  userPosition = [0, 0];


  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams,
   public modalCtrl: ModalController, public locations: Locations,public platform: Platform) {
  }

  openCamhsPage(){
    this.platform.ready().then(() => {
      let options = {
        timeout: 10000,
      enableHighAccuracy: true
      };
            Geolocation.getCurrentPosition(options).then((data) => {
                Locations.userPosition[0] = Math.round(data.coords.latitude * 100)/100;
                Locations.userPosition[1] = Math.round(data.coords.longitude * 100)/100;
                // console.log("CONTACT "+Locations.userPosition);
            });
        });
    this.locations.load();
    this.navCtrl.push(CamhsPage);
    console.log("CONTACT "+Locations.userPosition);
  }

  //Open WebPage
  openPage(url) {
    new InAppBrowser(url, '_system');
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Prerequisite : Check whether you have switch ON your GPS service in Android.

Also it is good to have Success and Error Callbacks to identify the actual Error. Something like below :

```
        .......... 
        // Success callback for get geo coordinates

        var onSuccess = function (data) {

            Locations.userPosition[0] = Math.round(data.coords.latitude * 100)/100;
            Locations.userPosition[1] = Math.round(data.coords.longitude * 100)/100;
        }

        var onError = function (data) {
            console.log("Not Able to get Geolocation");
        }

        openCamhsPage(){
            this.platform.ready().then(() => {
               Geolocation.getCurrentPosition(onSuccess, onError, { enableHighAccuracy: true });

            this.locations.load();
            this.navCtrl.push(CamhsPage);
            console.log("CONTACT "+Locations.userPosition);
          }
.......
.......
```